# Rails condition based on URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi im working on a Rails app, i didnt write the whole app, there is a part where i need to Echo a meesage if the user is Elite.. i know that in the URL i have the info

```
sign_up?locale=en&t=elite
```

Is there any chance i can use that in view to do something like you would do a GET condition pn PHP?

i mean `if (t=elite) {echo this} else {}`

Hope anyone can give me an easy solution for this, that not requiere wirte a hole method just for echoing 1 little message just for that kind of users.

thanks, also just as note im a noob on rails, but im doing just HTML/CSS integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query parameters are available in the [`params` Hash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) on each request:

```
<% if "elite" == params[:t] %>Check it out<% end %>
```